# Python and excel reading files problem

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I am sorry if this is a silly question but I have been working on this for hours and I cannot make it work. Please help!

I have a .txt file that originated from Excel. The file contains strings and numbers but I am only interested in the numbers, which is why I skip the first line and I only read from column 2 on.

```
   from numpy import *
```

I load it into Python doing

```
    infile = open('europenewMatrix.txt','r')
    infile.readline() # skip the first line
    numbers = [line.split(',')[2:] for line in infile.readlines()]
    infile.close()
```

because I need to do computations with this, I convert it into a matrix:

```
    travelMat = array(numbers)
```

ok, but this didn't convert the strings into integers, so I manually do it:

```
    for i in xrange(len(numbers)):
        for j in xrange(len(numbers)):
            travelMat[i,j] = int(self.travelMat[i,j])
        #end for
```

At this point, I was hoping that all my entries would be integers
but if I do

```
    print 'type is',type(self.travelMat[1,2])
```

the answer is:

```
type is <type 'numpy.string_'>
```

how can I really convert all my entries into integers?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the numbers as you read them, before creating the array:

```
infile = open('europenewMatrix.txt','r')
infile.readline() # skip the first line
numbers = []
for line in infile:
    numbers.append([int(val) for val in line.split(',')[2:]])
infile.close()
travelMat = array(numbers)
```

Comment: still there's a missing bracket in line 5 :o)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a csv or csv-like file, use the csv standard library module.

```
from numpy import *
import csv

infile = open('europenewMatrix.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(infile)
reader.next() # skip the first line
numbers = [[int(num) for num in row[2:]] for row in reader]
infile.close()

travelmat = array(numbers)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: 'from numpy import *' is not very good, so it would be better if you  fix this

Comment: @artsiom-rudzenka I agree, but it was outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: @user - maybe yes but maybe not - i believe that it is always better to give an advice to questioner

Answer (score 0):

if someone has a question that could have the same title but uses real Excel (.xls) files, try this (using module [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)):

```
import xlrd
import numpy as np

sheet = xlrd.open_workbook('test_readxls.xls').sheet_by_name('sheet1')
n_rows, n_cols = 5,2
data = np.zeros((n_rows, n_cols))
for row in range(n_rows):
    for col in range(n_cols):
        data[row,col] = float(sheet.cell(row,col).value)
```